# Vue JS get Json object list with axios

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, rest, vue-multiselect

I need to access this Json object

```
"savings": {
        "1": {
            "id": 111,
            "name": "savings A"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "savings B"
        },
    },
```

to display it on a mutiselect:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Savings:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <multiselect2
            v-model="savings"
            track-by="name"
            label="name"
            :options="savings_list"
            :allow-empty="false"
            :searchable="true">
         </multiselect2>
     </div>
 </div>

////
data: () => ({savings_list: [], savings: null});
////

axios.get('/api/)
        .then(response => {
    
            this.savings_list = response.data.savings;
            this.savings = this.savings_list.find(f => f.id>=0);}
```

I tried to declare savings as but no luck

```
savings_list: {array: {}}
```

I did this same process for other arrays and there was no issue, the problem here is I don´t know how to access this Json object using Vue.
When I run the code I get this errors:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Object

[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "filteredOptions": "TypeError: this.options.concat is not a function"
```

I've been stuck trying to fix this for hours, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear.  options expects an Array, but response.data.savings is an object

Comment: Yeah, I get that. The problem is I don't know how to convert the object into an array

Answer (score 0):

eventually you can try this

````
     .then(response => {
       let new_savings_list = [];
       for(saving in response.data.savings){
         new_savings_list.push(response.data.savings[saving]);
       }
       this.savings_list = new_savings_list;```
````